# startAfter() with google firestore are not working as expected

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Am trying to slice my fetched items as am using IonInfinite scrolling in my ionic4 project.

Here is how am trying to do it :

**declaring variable to define the latest entry and doing 1st query**

```js
  latestEntry: any;
  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    this.dressCollection = db.collection<Dress>('dress', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(10));
    console.log(this.dressCollection);
    this.dressCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.latestEntry = data[data.length - 1];
    });
    this.dress = this.dressCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
```

**Then triggering another set of functions when the `IonInfinite scrolls end which is like this:**

```js
  anotherGetDresses() {
    this.finalAnotherGetDresses();
    return this.dress;
  }
  finalAnotherGetDresses() {
    console.log(this.latestEntry);
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    this.dressCollection = this.db.collection<Dress>('dress', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').startAfter(this.latestEntry).limit(10));
    this.dressCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.latestEntry = data[data.length - 1];
    });
    this.dress = this.dressCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

so am trying to declar the second time query starting after the latest entry from the last one... it just loads and print what should be printed on console .. but not updating or fetching any items.